# Overflow button forces Action Mode to finish

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an EditText and I want the user to be able to select some text and apply some basic formatting to the selected text (bold, italic, etc). I still want the standard copy, cut, paste options to show, though. I read somewhere in the Android documentation that to do this, you should call setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback() on the EditText and pass it an ActionModeCallback(), so that's what I did. Here's my code:

In my activity's onCreate() method:

```
myEditText.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new TextSelectionActionMode());
```

Callback declaration:

```
private class TextSelectionActionMode implements ActionMode.Callback {
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        menu.add("Bold");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I click on the overflow button (to access my "Bold" menu item), the ActionMode gets closed immediately. If I set it to always show as an action, using this:

```
MenuItem bold = menu.add("Bold");
bold.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

It works fine and I can click on it (though it obviously does nothing). What am I missing here?

*Edit: Just wanted to add that I run into the exact same problem if I actually inflate a menu instead of adding menu items programmatically. Once again, though, the problem goes away if I force it to always show as an action.*

Answer (score 3):

It's frameworks issue. If textview receive 'focus changed' event, then textview stop the action mode. When overflow popup is shown, textview miss focus.

Comment: Ok so how do you prevent the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been solved in Android 6.0. However you should use [ActionMode.Callback2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.Callback2.html) as described [here](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#behavior-test-selection) in Android 6.0.

For Android 5.x and below, I recommend this workaround: add a button to `Toolbar` or `ActionBar` which records the current selection and then open another context menu.

```
this.inputText_selectionStart = inputText.getSelectionStart();
this.inputText_selectionEnd = inputText.getSelectionEnd();
registerForContextMenu(inputText);
openContextMenu(inputText);
unregisterForContextMenu(inputText);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a filed Android bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82640.
That link contains a workaround. Fortunately this has been fixed in Android 6.0.